# is a state changing href in an email an acceptable security risk?

Tags: email, security, csrf

I want to add a button to an email that will then open an api endpoint that changes some state in my webapp. The endpoint requires that the user is already logged in to the website but I was wondering if there are other security concerns I should be aware of. I.e. I will need to use GET instead of POST since it is an href in an email. This will also not include a CSRF token.

Is this generally something I shouldn't do or are there some best practices?

One way would be to just open the webapp through the href and then require the actual action to be triggered through a form/post request within the webapp.

However I would like to avoid this extra step.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a button to an email

Any JS code is forbidden in message bodies in Outlook. The best what you could do is to create a hyperlink.

> The endpoint requires that the user is already logged in to the website

The default web browser will be launched when a hyperlink is clicked in Outlook. It is not necessarily that a user is logged on using a default web browser. So, there is a chance to get a hyperlink navigated in a browser where you/users are not authorized.

> One way would be to just open the webapp through the href and then require the actual action to be triggered through a form/post request within the webapp.

This is the most reliable solution in your scenario. Also you may consider creating creating an add-in for email client applications. For example, for Outlook you may develop a web-based add-in, see [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) for more information.